# Filtering a report query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Still a beginning access programmer here. Trying to get the report to work. Here is what I am doing

I first created a report using the Report Wizard using the following query as input

```
SELECT EmployeeId, Project, StartDate
FROM Tasks;
```

I have a form wherein I select the employee-id. I want to filter the report based on the employee id selected. Here is what I have for invoking the report

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEmpWork", acViewPreview, "qryEmpReport", "EmployeeId = " & strempid
```

qryEmpReport is the name of the query that holds the report query that I mentioned above. The strempid holds the value that was selected in the form. However when I get around to execute this, it prompts me to enter the employee id again. Any ideas as to why I am getting this? I have validated to make sure that the strempid does contain the value selected earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll guess `Tasks.EmployeeId` is text datatype.  If my guess is correct, add quotes around the value you supply for `EmployeeId`:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEmpWork", acViewPreview, "qryEmpReport", "EmployeeId = '" & strempid & "'"
```

Based on our trouble-shooting exercise in the comments, I think you should give yourself an opportunity to examine the actual string value you're giving to `OpenReport` for its *WhereCondition* argument.  (It's better to view the actual string instead of trying to imagine what it looks like.)

```
Dim strWhereCondition As String
strWhereCondition = "EmployeeId = '" & strempid & "'"
Debug.Print "strWhereCondition ->" & strWhereCondition & "<-"
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEmpWork", acViewPreview, "qryEmpReport", strWhereCondition
```

View the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely took the prompt away but the report comes up empty. There is data that satisfies the condition in the table. Do I have to trim the strempid?

Comment: Run this parameter query in Access' query designer and plug in your *strempid* value when it prompts you for *which employee id*: `SELECT EmployeeId, Project, StartDate FROM Tasks WHERE EmployeeId = [which employee id];`  Does it return any records?  If so, are they the records you expect?

Comment: that works fine. Returns the 1 row that I expect. here is the query            SELECT EmployeeId, Project, StartDate
FROM Tasks
WHERE EmployeeId = 'A111111'. I did use the query to prompt. I meant to indicate what I had entered

Comment: OK, then in your code, on the line before `DoCmd.OpenReport`, add this line: `Debug.Print "EmployeeId = '" & strempid & "'"`  Then run the code and look at the output from `Debug.Print` in the Immediate window.  What does it show you?

Comment: here is what I see in the window  EmployeeId = 'A111111'

Comment: my bad. had a space after the quote that you had asked me to add. Works great. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it